# How many solutions does the equation $x^2-y^2 = 3^8\cdot 5^6\cdot 13^4$ have? Given that $x$ and $y$ are positive integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:** How many solutions does the equation $x^2-y^2 = 3^8\cdot 5^6\cdot 13^4$ have? Given that $x$ and $y$ are positive integers.

---

I tried a similar approach to the ones described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286212/how-many-solutions-does-the-equation-x2-y2-529-have-given-that-x-and/2286231#2286231), but to no avail. I can't split up the RHS so that all the factors have the same base.

Comment: You can start by factoring the LHS. Since the RHS is a perfect odd square, the LHS must be too. This should help you deduce which factors appear in x, y or their sums/differences.

Comment: Alternatively, you could move y^2 to the RHS, note that you have a Pythagorean triple, and use the general formula for Pythagorean triples to reduce the search space.

Comment: How do you deduce that RHS is a perfect odd square by hand? Care to elaborate on your second comment?

Comment: The prime factors are all odd, and the powers all even - nothing more to it. And I thought some more trickery was needed to solve this as maybe not all ways to split the numbers in two would lead to valid x, y, but the answers below show it's simpler than what I suggested.

Answer (score 7):

Factor
$$ (x+y)(x-y) = 3^8 \cdot 5^6 \cdot 13^4 $$
The number of ways to split up $3^8$ in a product is 9. The number of ways to split up $5^6$ in a product is 7. The number of ways to split up $13^4$ in a product is 5. Collectively this means $3^8 \cdot 5^6 \cdot 13^4$ can be split into a product in $9\cdot7\cdot5=315$ ways.

Since $2$ is not a factor, both factors in the product are odd. The value of $x$, that makes $(x+y)(x-y)$ be equal to the desired value, is the average of the the two factors in the product. Since the average of two positive odd integers is a positive integer, $x$ is always a positive integer.

Let $a = x+y$ and $b = x-y$. The 315 ways to split up the product can be divided into three groups: $a>b$, $a<b$ and $a=b$.

- The group $a=b$: There is one value in this group, and that's the one where $a=b=3^4\cdot5^3\cdot13^2$. In this case we have $y=0$, so it is not a solution.
- Every element in $a<b$ has a corresponding element in $a>b$: (the one where each power is swapped). Since only the ones in $a>b$ have $y>0$, only half of those not in $a=b$ are valid.

This means there are $(315-1)/2 = 157$ solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The product $n=3^8\cdot 5^6\cdot13^4$ has a total of $(8+1)(6+1)(4+1)=315$ factors $d$. Those can be paired up as $(d,n/d)$. For the choice $d=n/d=\sqrt n$ the two factors are equal. For the remaining $157=(315-1)/2$ pairs we must use the bigger one as $x+y$ and the smaller as $x-y$. Because all the factors $d, n/d$ are odd, the resulting system has a solution $(x,y)$ in integers.

The answer is thus $157$. They come from solutions of the system $x+y=n/d, x-y=d$, that is,
$$
x=\frac{(n/d)+d}2,\quad y=\frac{(n/d)-d}2,
$$
with $d$ ranging over the set of factors $<\sqrt n$.